# Searching whole system for files with specific inode

Tags: linux, command, search, inode

I technically know how to do all these things, but combining it is problematic.
Inode is saved in first line of text file (I can eventually read it directly from file), I need results saved to the same file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` utility with `-inum` parameter. From [man 1 find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-inum n`
>
> File has inode number `n`.  It is normally easier to use the
>
> `-samefile` test instead.

Comment: I have tried "locate -inum ls -i /home/user/file | cat>file2" and it's giving me error "locate: invalid value 'um' of --limit". I have found that locate is used to find files in whole system.

Comment: @Corporal Girrafe Please, use `find` instead of `locate`.

Comment: But won't `find` search only in folder where script is located?

Comment: I have came up with something like that - `find -ls ln -i /home/user/folder/file | cat>>save` but i get `find: paths must precede expression ln` error. And this is the issue, i don't have the path, i want to search in whole system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` command with the argument `-inum` with inode number like as below

Example-

```
touch /home/ajeet/original_file.txt
ln /home/ajeet/original_file.txt /root/hard_link_file.txt

ls -li /root/hard_link_file.txt
1704088 -rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 May 24 18:24 /root/hard_link_file.txt

ls -li /home/ajeet/original_file.txt
1704088 -rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 May 24 18:24 /home/ajeet/original_file.txt

find / -inum 1704088
/home/ajeet/original_file.txt
/root/hard_link_file.txt
```